# Installing Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 in a VMware

Tags: server, webserver

Hi everyone I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 in a VMware station on my iMAC which is running on an intel core i5. My question is which kernel should I install? The options are:

1. linux-signed-generic-lts-utopic
2. linux-generic-lts-utopic
3. linux-virtual-lts-utopic
4. linux-signed-image-generic-lts-utopic
5. linux-image-extra-3.16.0-30-generic
6. linux-image-generic-lts-utopic
7. linux-image-virtual-lts-utopic
8. linux-signed-image-3.16.0-30-generic
9. linux-image-3.16.0-30-generic

What is the difference between these kernels and which kernel is best with VMware?

Comment: +1 I have no clue what the differences are between the options and a google search leads here

Comment: As it stands, your question is primarily opinion-based. Please refrain from questions like “which is the best X?”. Instead, you can ask “What are the differences between the available X?”. See [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 1):

This partially depends on your use case.  the LTS versions are all Long Term Support and are meant for production installs.  Personally, I only use LTS versions so that I can ensure that there will be support for more than a few years.

If you are just looking to test stuff out, I would go with the linux-virtual-lts-utopic kernel, but if you are looking to mimic a realworld server, I would go with the linux-generic-lts-utopic.

Ultimately the choice is yours though.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the servers will install the 'generic' kernel metapackages that point to the correct linux image for that release.

To that end, use the defaults that were installed with the server installation, as the disk is smart enough to determine which kernel you need.  (Unless you have a specialized use case, which is unlikely in a VMware setup)

You should also consider *not* asking broad questions such as this.

The `lts-utopic` kernel is just an update of the LInux kernel which includes the Utopic hardware enablement stack as well as some kernel updates.  You may wish to use this, but it is not required, as you are on VMware and don't necessarily need the updated HWE stack.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are going to do with the image.

In general you are not going to notice a huge difference between the kernels in terms of performance.

I would use either the virtual or the server kernel (assuming you are running a server). If you are running a desktop , generic would work as well .

see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Dev/Flavours